# PySimpleGUI -- How do I detect a window move event

Tags: windows, events, pysimplegui

I'm using PySimpleGUI and need to detect a window move event but I don't see any window move event. How do we detect the move then?

Thank you...

I searched the PySimpleGUI documentation. I saw something for resizing but not for detecting a move. I thought I would find something like:

if event == psg.WIN_MOVED but I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Import the Module -  `import PySimpleGUI as sg`
2. Create a window - `window = sg.Window("My Window", layout)`
3. Set the initial position of the window  - `window.TKroot.geometry("400x200+100+100")`
4. Create a loop to continuously read events -

```
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        # Check if the window position has changed
        if window.TKroot.geometry() != "400x200+100+100":
            print("Window moved!")
```

I hope that helps and answers your question, if so please mark my answer as correct!

Comment: I'm getting an error:

window.TKroot.geometry("800x400+50+50")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Comment: This statement should be added after window finalized, like `Window('title', layout, finalize=True)`, or after `window.read()`.

Comment: It looks like one option missed in the code, `window.read(timeout=200)`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by binding the `'<Configure>'` event to window after it finalized.

Answer (score 0):

You can get window movement resize events by setting the parameter `enable_window_config_events` when creating the window.

[This Demo Program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Window_Config_Events.py) shows an example similar to this one:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('Config Events')],
            [sg.Text( key='-INFO-')],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Config Information', layout, enable_window_config_events=True, font='_ 14')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == sg.WINDOW_CONFIG_EVENT:
        window['-INFO-'].update(f'Location = {window.current_location()}\nSize = {window.size}')

window.close()
```

Using this method is going to be the most efficient method.  Using a timeout on the `read` will cause latency and needless use of CPU time.

[image]